# Change user locale in AIX

Tags: utf-8, locale, aix

Good day,

In one of my AIX server, let say server 1, I login as db2inst1, and enter command `locale`, then I get this:

```
bash-4.3$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

And in my another AIX server, let say server 2, I login as db2inst1, and enter command `locale`, then I get this:

```
bash-4.3$ locale
LANG=EN_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_ALL=en_US
```

I would like to change the value of "en_US" to "en_US.UTF-8". So, I login as root, then go to `smitty -> System Environments -> Manage Language Environment
-> Set User Languages`, follow by key in the username `db2inst1`, but I cant see anything that allow me to changed to "en_US.UTF-8".

I am suspecting I am doing in the wrong way. Trying to google but still cant get the correct way to do it. Kindly advise.

Comment: On AIX, `EN_US` means `EN_US.UTF-8`, `en_US` means `en_US.ISO8859-1`. Quite non-standard, mind you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Go to ~/.profile

update this value:

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

and save.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install EN_US on server 2. Extra locales are inside the AIX install CD. So insert the CD into CD-ROM at first.

```sh
root@aix6:/$ smit mlang
->Change/Show Primary Language Environment                    #Press Enter
---->Change/show Cultural Convention, Language, or Keyboard   #Press Enter
---->Primary CULTURAL convention                              #Press F4, move cursor to "UTF-8 English (United States) [EN_US]", press Enter
---->Primary LANGUAGE translation                             #Press F4, move cursor to "UTF-8 English (United States) [EN_US]", press Enter
---->Primary Keyboard                                         #Press F4, move cursor to "UTF-8 English(POSIX) KBD ID 103P [EN_US]", press Enter
```

This will install `X11.loc.EN_US.bash.rte`, `bos.msg.EN_US.rte` etc. and set the system locale to `EN_US`. Relogin to see the locale change.

```sh
root@aix6:/$ locale charmap
UTF-8
root@aix6:/$ locale -a
C
POSIX
EN_US.UTF-8
EN_US
en_US.8859-15
en_US.ISO8859-1
en_US
root@aix6:/$ locale
LANG=EN_US
LC_COLLATE="EN_US"
LC_CTYPE="EN_US"
LC_MONETARY="EN_US"
LC_NUMERIC="EN_US"
LC_TIME="EN_US"
LC_MESSAGES="EN_US"
LC_ALL=
```